# Replacement for "program_invocation_name"

Tags: android, c++, linux, c++14, gnu

In the man page of "program_invocation_name" it is mentioned that:
**These variables are GNU extensions, and should not be used in programs intended to be portable.**

Is there any known/possible replacement for "program_invocation_name", if you do not have access to `main` and its arguments?

Comment: The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/program_invocation_name.3.html) says that *"This is the same as the value of `argv[0]` in `main()`"*...

Comment: [**program_invocation_name(3) - Linux man page**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/program_invocation_name) mentions a possible alternative as well: _This is the same as the value of argv[0] in main()_ So, you may store `argv[0]` in `main()`. Btw. actually, it's only a convention to pass the program name in `argv[0]` (but I never saw anything what didn't consider that convention).

Comment: `argv` is a parameter in `main()` and hence not global. This doesn't prevent you to invent your own global variable which is assigned in `main()`.

Comment: @Scheff Sry what if this comes in some library that is used by different applications? For me, this function was best, and is there a better way than having it defined in all the main() functions?

Comment: I guess there are not many choices you have. Either you limit your scope to a specific implementation like GNU (GNU is not that exotic.) or you try to write portable code by excluding stuff which is not part of `std::` API (or any other portable library). Or, you chose an intermediate approach (with `#ifdef`s) where certain features of your S/W are available on specific systems only. You may try to make a somehow portable impl. on your own. E.g. the Windows API has something comparable: `GetModuleFileName()`.